# How to get calendar notifications using Microsoft Office 365 webapp?

Tags: 14.04, webapps, calendar, office365

My company recently made a switch to using Microsoft Office 365.

As I am one of the Ubuntu users, I am trying to set up a workflow with its calendar.

I want to:

- get reminder notifications for upcoming meetings
- get push notifications for planned meetings, and be able to accept or reject them via push

Right now, I have to pull the information by opening the calendar manually. And as I cannot use the Office Suite, I am wondering what options I have using the web app.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think it is possible to integrate some of the Office email calendar etc into the Evolution client